# How to save different classes in the same file

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

So I have downloaded an asset for Unity called "JSON .NET For Unity", and I got it working, but I have a problem.

I have different classes and variables and I want to store them, the problem its that I dont know how to save them in the same file. I have a different method for each thing that I want to save but I dont know how to do that in the same method or making it write in the same file.

This is one example: In this method I save the class named World and I get it from the file. I have other methods like this one that asks for different things (a list, a variable...)

```
    public void SaveWorld(World worldToSave)
{
    SaveSystem.Init();
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(worldToSave, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
    });
    File.WriteAllText(SaveSystem.SAVE_FOLDER + "/Save.json", json);
}
public World LoadWorld()
{
    World saveWorld = null;
    if (File.Exists(SaveSystem.SAVE_FOLDER + "/Save.json"))
    {
        string saveString = File.ReadAllText(SaveSystem.SAVE_FOLDER + "/Save.json");
        saveWorld = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<World>(saveString, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize

        });
    }
    return saveWorld;
}
```

Then for saving I would call this:

```
    void Save()
{
    saveLoadSystem.SaveWorld(worldHandler.World);
    saveLoadSystem.SaveInstalledObjects(worldHandler.installedObjectList);
    saveLoadSystem.SaveUnits(unitHandler.unitList);
}
```

Where saveLoadSystem is the script that has all the methods.

Thank you

Edit: Using Hacettepe Hesabı answer.

I can save correctly like he said and saving a class that only contains an int called numData and another script with a List of ints I get this:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "numData": 2
}[
  0,
  1
]
```

The problem is that when I load I get this error:

JsonReaderException: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: [. Path '', line 4, position 1.

For loading Im using the next method:

```
    public DATA LoadData()
{
    DATA saveData = null;
    if (File.Exists(SaveSystem.SAVE_FOLDER + "/Save.json"))
    {
        string saveString = File.ReadAllText(SaveSystem.SAVE_FOLDER + "/Save.json");
        saveData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DATA>(saveString, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize

        });
    }
    return saveData;
}
```

Comment: JSON allows nesting (you can put a JSON object inside another JSON object).  I don't know your particular JSON library so I can't offer a full answer but what you want to do is add all 3 of your objects with named keys to a single JSON object and serialize that to file.

Answer (score 2):

To save them all to the same file you could have the three instances in the same class and then save that class.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but it would be a very large class and I would like to have each thing in its place (For example mixing the world with the prices)

Comment: i would think of it being a kind of collection class that would just contain the three instances of the three different classes that you can create and pass into the json functions.  of course you would have to tweak your saving/loading code but it would still allow you to keep your original three classes and just utilize this new class for saving/loading